# Android create bitmap from RGB 2D arrays

Tags: android, bitmap, rgb, pixel

I am working on an android watermarking project, and I need to make a method to generate 2D arrays for R,G and B and recreate the image after getting it back from the WM method that is done by someone else.(I don't have this method, so I can't change it).

Here is how I created the R,G, B from the bitmap:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/Watermarking/WM_20151208_183746_1282108897-1.jpg");
int height = image.getHeight();
int width = image.getWidth();
short [][] red = new short[height][width];
short [][] green = new short[height][width];
short [][] blue = new short[height][width];
int column = 0;
int row = 0;
while(row < height)
{
    while(column < width)
    {
        int pixel = image.getPixel(column, row);
        red[row][column] = (short) Color.red(pixel);
        green[row][column] = (short) Color.green(pixel);
        blue[row][column] = (short) Color.blue(pixel);
        column++;
    }
    row++;
}
displayImage(red, green, blue);
```

And here is the method that I am doing to test that what I did was correct:

```
public void displayImage(short [][] red, short [][] green, short [][] blue)
{
    short height = (short) red.length;
    short width = (short) red[0].length;
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    int column = 0;
    int row = 0;
    while(row < height)
    {
        while(column < width)
        {
            image.setPixel(column, row, Color.rgb(red[row][column], green[row][column], blue[row][column]));
            column++;
        }
        row++;
    }

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap (image);
}
```

The image that appears is a black image, even though it should be correct. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by simply debugging your code, you are only filling the first row of the array repeatedly by not resetting the column variable

add:

```
column = 0;
```

after both loops (in filling and reading the array);